# Powershell.exe command keeps opening 2x during windows 10 Launching

Tags: windows, powershell, script, shell-script, virus

[image: Registry location Image]

`powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location -literalPath '%V'`

HOW do i delete this regkey??? its blocked for removal,

everytime i launch my windows 10 i get 2x a powershell.exe scipt  opening this command 2 times:

```ps
powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location -literalPath '%V'
```

Location   :

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\command
```

cannot be deleted from command key, any changes are blocked.

AND IT DRIVES me nuts...as i have seen a viral infection called: powershell.exe

Will it help removing everything from powershell? like uninstalling this powershell module  from windows instalation?

PS my mouse keeps dancing/freezing now and then after the scripts are opened.

Comment: PowerShell is certainly not a virus, and my computer has exactly the same registry entry and it's only part of the context-menu. Include in your post a screenshot of what you see after the boot.

Comment: If I hold the shift key and then right-click the empty background of a folder in explorer, I get a context menu item "Open Powershell Window Here" which is what the command in your registry screenshot would do. This is default windows-10 behavior. So I think this is an X/Y problem: the real question is why this command is being called. I would look for hotkeys autohotkey etc.. I would also try using Autoruns (microsoft sysinternals free program) to see if there is an unusual script that may be invoking the command. Finally, I would check your mouse, especially if it programmable. (cont)

Comment: I have seen certain "gaming mice" have odd issues with dancing, freezing, and odd scroll-lock behavior that was either driver related or even dirt related.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/85Tog.png

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2rWw.png